# disable (note hide) vertical scroll when the modal is open

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

When the modal is open, it is not ideal to keep vertical scrolling. Thats why in the useEffect of my component I did this:

```
if (state.modal) {
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.style.paddingRight = "17px";
}

return () => {
  document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
  document.body.style.paddingRight = "0px";
};
```

Although, it hides the scrollbar, now the problem is, the browser is moved because of scrollbar hiding and show.

so that, I want to keep the scroll bar but disable it when the modal is open.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of solving this. hope it will work.

on your `useEffect` do the following:

```
if (state.modal) {
  document.body.style.position = "fixed";
  document.body.style.width = "100%";
  document.body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
}

return () => {
  document.body.style.position = "static";
  document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
};
```